# Gerrit GitBlit Plugin shows no Branch Graph

Tags: gerrit, gitblit

we are using a Gerrit Server to manage our Repos. In addition we use the Gitblit Plugin as an addition to browse these Repos.

Since Gitblit version 1.4.0 it should be possible to show a Branch Graph (something equivalent to 'git log --graph') next to the name of the branches.

Everything seems to be working fine so far. But the Image of the Branch Graph cannot be loaded. It's like this for every project.

When looking in the logs i can't find anything in der ERROR_LOG but the HTTPD_LOG shows the following Message:

```
192.168.XXX.XXX - - [12/Mrz/2014:09:22:01 +0100] "GET
/plugins/gitblit/graph/?r=project.git&h=b000f099495c6e9ebe84b862ff8f7c518af4b3c1&l=20
HTTP/1.1" 404 9
"http://192.168.XXX.XXX:8080/plugins/gitblit/summary/?r=project.git"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?
Or has some other ideas where i can look for the problem. I'm pretty clueless without anymore information.

I hope you can help me

Cheers 
Andi

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the gitblit plugin. See https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2942 That bug report contains a patch to fix this.